Is it "Anyone knows how to..." or "Anyone know how to..."
Without the "does". What is the correct verb conjugation to use with "anyone" in the sentence "Anyone [know/knows] how to..."?

Leaving out the initial Does renders the sentence very informal. In any event, even when it is left out, English speakers nonetheless understand it to be there. So the sentence would be Anyone know how to…?

Without does, it all depends on the right intonation. Anyone knows how to do this is also correct, but it would now be a statement and have a different meaning.

Sorry, Peter. That's simply not so. I think Paul Tanenbaum's Answer is so obviously correct, it doesn't matter how adequate his explanation is.
Unless it's a partial quotation and you left out some relevant context, in 60 years of listening I've never once noticed anyone saying 'Anyone knows how to do this…'
You might get away with 'Everyone knows…' or 'Anyone can tell…' but neither is strictly comparable to native ears; very much less so for learners.
